# CSS equal sides box-shadow around table row and its cells as one block

Tags: html, css

I am hiding cells overflow to always display one line rows.

On hover of a row I show display of all cells that have more than one line of content.

I am highlighting the row among its child ".content" divs of each cell.

I wish to add a box-shadow attribute defined in a way that it drops a shadow around the whole row respecting the cell content overflow outline. I don't want shadow between cells(inside the "row block") and I'd like the shadow to drop equally on all sides.

Current code and image:

```css
        .tableWrap {

          overflow: scroll;

          position: relative;

        }

        .superResponsive {

          width: 100%;

          border-collapse: collapse;

          color: #0887A7!important;

        }

        body:not(.nohover) .superResponsive tbody tr:hover {

          background-color: rgba(173, 216, 230, 0.5);

        }

        .superResponsive td,

        .superResponsive th {

          border: 1px solid lightBlue;

          height: 30px;

          max-height: 30px;

          min-height: 30px;

          vertical-align: top;

          min-width: 90px;

          width: 200px;

          position: relative;

        }

        .content {

          min-height: 25x;

          overflow: hidden;

          width: auto;

          height: 25px;

          padding: 5px;

          /*transition:all .2s;*/

        }

        .superResponsive tr:hover .content {

          background: white;

          color: Coral;

          overflow: visible;

          position: absolute;

          z-index: 100;

          box-shadow: .2px .2px #007d9a, .5px .5px #007d9a, 1.5px 1.5px #007d9a, 2px 2px #007d9a, 2px 2px #007d9a, 3px 3px #007d9a, 3px 3px #007d9a, 4px 4px #007d9a;

          /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 28px 15px rgba(209,209,209,0.47);*/

          min-height: 100%;

          height: auto;

          left: 0;

          right: 0;

          /* border: 1px solid lightBlue;*/

        }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="superResponsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>TEST</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>Col n</th>
        <th>LAST</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
            <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
            <p>Some DataSome DataSome DataSome Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">

          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
            <p>Some Data</p>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: my current code without the box shadow i want:

http://jsfiddle.net/coolcatDev/r190r8hn/10/

Comment: Alternative cool design suggestions are very much welcome ;)